# Buckling of supported pillar

Tags: structural-engineering, structural-analysis

I am wondering how the "buckling number" of a timber column is altered by having a vertical element attached to it. Blue is the roof, green a concrete wall and black is the timber column and the beam.

I am basically asking what happens to "K" as described here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckling#Columns

[image]

Comment: Symmetric or assymmetric load?

Comment: @SolarMike the load should come stright down the pillar i.e parallell

Answer (score 0):

To be on the safe side, you could use $K=2$ for one end fixed and the other one free to move laterally. However, you may also need to [take into account load eccentricity](https://www.continuummechanics.org/eccentriccolumnbuckling.html), because the beam in question is most likely loaded not only by the axial force but also by a bending moment or in other words loaded by axial force acting at some offset from the beam center.

In practice, since the beams are not perfect, basically causing inherent eccentricity even for cases with axial load on axis only, this should be taken into account. For example in Eurocodes, the [Perry-Robertson formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perry%E2%80%93Robertson_formula) is used for that.

Comment: Thanks! Both ends are fixed as far as I understand. Thus $K$ can be choosen as $0.65$ according to this document. https://civilengineering.blog/2017/09/12/equivalent-lengths-of-columns/#jp-carousel-1490

Comment: It depends if you are designing the beam or assessing existing beam. I would use safer values for the latter, and if the calculation is ok, you have additional margin of safety. Designing is of course more difficult, because you may be tempted to go closer to the limit state. [This app](https://eurocodeapplied.com/design/en1993/flanged-steel-beam-column-uls-design) might be useful, even though it is primarily for steel beams.

Comment: Thanks again, it is an existing column with a beam that both needs fire coating, the amout of which depends on $\frac{l_{c}}{h}$ where $h$ is the size and $l_{c}$ the effective lenght i.e $K \cdot L$.